# How can I change my code to jQuery instead of pure JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set a function on jQuery instead of pure JS and I am getting an error:

```
 15 | prev.css('height') = prev.scrollHeight + "px";
                                               ^ Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
```

This is the actual code:

```js
function expand(target)
{
  let prev = target.previousElementSibling;
  
  prev.style.height = prev.scrollHeight + "px";
  target.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#p {
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#read-more {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,255,255,1));
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='wrapper'>
  <p id='p'>Pinterest taxidermy et heirloom, ennui enim eu bicycle rights fugiat nesciunt commodo. High Life food truck jean shorts in. Blog asymmetrical cold-pressed photo booth. Neutra chia in, mustache Etsy nostrud plaid kogi. Magna polaroid stumptown aliqua put a bird on it gentrify, street art craft beer bicycle rights skateboard. DIY plaid gentrify, sustainable sapiente seitan mumblecore viral cardigan. Nisi pariatur laborum cornhole kitsch tempor fingerstache Bushwick. </p>
  <div id='read-more' onclick="expand(this)">
    READ MORE
  </div>
</div>
```

And I am trying to set that here:

```
var toggleReadMore = function() {
    $('#read-more').click(function(e) {
        var prev = $(this).prev();            
        prev.css('height') = prev.scrollHeight + "px";
        $(this).hide();            
    });
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign the value like that, you need to change it to something like

```
prev.css('height', prev.scrollHeight)
```

Where the second argument accepts the scroll height. In case of multiple CSS properties, you can pass an object like

```
prev.css({
  height: 'some height here',
  width: 'some width here'
});
```

Comment: I already changed it and my code is still not doing what I want.

Comment: @TheUnnamed Your question was.. "Why that error" to which I've answered, now am not sure what's your next question.

Answer (score 1):

** Change 3rd line like below **

```
var toggleReadMore = function() {
$('#read-more').click(function(e) {
    var prev = $(this).prev();            
    prev.css('height', 50);
    $(this).hide();            
  });
};
```